# align index on the right-hand side

Tags: indentation, makeindex

Some index references are shown in the next line if there are too many sections with the same \index. This is fine, but I want to align it on the right-hand side (as shown in the picture below). How can I do this? 
I guess I should replace the `\hangindent 2em` in 
`\renewcommand*{\@idxitem}{\par\nopagebreak\hangindent 2em\hskip 0.8cm}`
but I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Index.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}"

delim_0 "\\hfill"

group_skip "\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\starttheindex"
postamble "\n\\stoptheindex\\end{theindex}"
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s Index.ist, columnsep=5mm] 
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand*{\indexpage}[5]{#2\ifnum#4=0 \else.#4\fi}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|%
   indexpage
    {\ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{section}}%
    {\ifnum\value{subsection}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{subsection}}}%
} 
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{%
  \indexrule
  \hspace*{1mm}\textbf{#1}\par
  \nopagebreak
  \vskip-\baselineskip
}
\newcommand*{\indexrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \vskip\dp\strutbox\nopagebreak
  \hrulefill\par\pagebreak[3]
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \hrulefill\par\nobreak
}
\newcommand*{\starttheindex}{\raggedcolumns}
\newcommand*{\stoptheindex}{\indexrule}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@idxitem}{\par\nopagebreak\hangindent 2em\hskip 0.8cm} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{English football league system}
\index{System}
%
\subsection{History}
Created in 1888.
%
\subsection{Structure}
\index{Structure}
At the top is the single division of the Premier League
%
\subsection{Cup eligibility}
\index{Cup}
Being members of a league at a particular level also affects eligibility for Cup.
%
\subsection{Sub 4}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 5}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 6}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 7}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 8}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 9}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Carabao Cup}
\index{Cup}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the problem using \raggedright and \raggedleft.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Index.ist}
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\indexheading{"
heading_suffix "}"

delim_0 "\\hfill"

group_skip "\n"
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\starttheindex"
postamble "\n\\stoptheindex\\end{theindex}"
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s Index.ist, columnsep=5mm] 
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand*{\indexpage}[5]{#2\ifnum#4=0 \else.#4\fi}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|%
   indexpage
    {\ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{section}}%
    {\ifnum\value{subsection}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{subsection}}}%
} 
\newcommand*{\indexheading}[1]{%
  \indexrule
  \raggedright\hspace*{1mm}\textbf{#1}\par % NEW CODE (with\raggedright)
  \nopagebreak
  \vskip-\baselineskip
}
\newcommand*{\indexrule}{%
  \par\nopagebreak
  \vskip\dp\strutbox\nopagebreak
  \hrulefill\par\pagebreak[3]
  \vskip -\baselineskip
  \hrulefill\par\nobreak
}
\newcommand*{\starttheindex}{\raggedcolumns}
\newcommand*{\stoptheindex}{\indexrule}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand*{\@idxitem}{\par\nopagebreak\hangindent 2em\raggedleft\hskip 0.8cm}  % NEW CODE (with \raggedleft)
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{English football league system}
\index{System}
%
\subsection{History}
Created in 1888.
%
\subsection{Structure}
\index{Structure}
At the top is the single division of the Premier League
%
\subsection{Cup eligibility}
\index{Cup}
Being members of a league at a particular level also affects eligibility for Cup.
%
\subsection{Sub 4}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 5}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 6}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 7}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 8}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Sub 9}
\index{Cup}
%
\subsection{Carabao Cup}
\index{Cup}

\printindex
\end{document}
```